# Trying to gdalwarp a TIFF results in mostly empty image with data at ends

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp

I'm trying to use `gdalwarp` to project an FAA source chart in `EPSG:9802` (Lambert Conic Conformal) to `EPSG:3395` (World Mercator). The issue is that part of the data is east of longitude -180, and part is west. So when I try this:

```
/usr/bin/gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:3395 -dstalpha -overwrite Lambert.tif Mercator.tif
```

I end up with a large, mostly empty image spanning 360 degrees of longitude, with the data small and distorted at the extreme left and right ends of the resulting TIFF.

I'm new to GDAL/projection but my research indicates that this might be because the central meridian of World Mercator is defined as 0 degrees.

I'm trying to find a way to use (for example) -180 degrees as the central meridian so that the resulting image in World Mercator is usable. If it makes it easier, I do **not** need the resulting World Mercator image to be georeferenced at all.

I've spent a couple of days trying various options to gdalwarp and gdal_translate but haven't made any progress. I've also spent a few hours trying to split the source TIFF into two (one west of -180 degrees and one east) and projecting them separately to World Mercator, so I could then manually combine the resulting images (which don't need to be georeferenced) with something like GIMP. Nothing has worked. Among various approaches I've tried `--config CENTER_LONG 180`, the `-te` option to gdalwarp, intermediate projection to Polar Stereographic, and others.
Any ideas?

gdalinfo for Lambert.tif:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: Lambert.tif
Size is 19587, 7468
Coordinate System is:
PROJCRS["AK_IFR",
    BASEGEOGCRS["NAD83",
        DATUM["North American Datum 1983",
            ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257221999999,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        ID["EPSG",4269]],
    CONVERSION["Lambert Conic Conformal (2SP)",
        METHOD["Lambert Conic Conformal (2SP)",
            ID["EPSG",9802]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of false origin",51,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8821]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of false origin",-154,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8822]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of 1st standard parallel",65,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8823]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of 2nd standard parallel",37,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8824]],
        PARAMETER["Easting at false origin",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8826]],
        PARAMETER["Northing at false origin",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8827]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["easting",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]],
        AXIS["northing",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
GeoTransform =
  -3327476.67088, 184.470564, 16.370996
  1268433.444758, 16.370185, -184.468772
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_DATETIME=2022:12:07 10:59:53
  TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=2 (pixels/inch)
  TIFFTAG_SOFTWARE=GPL Ghostscript 8.71
  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=400
  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=400
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-3327476.671, 1268433.445) (152d33'50.09"E, 50d55'42.07"N)
Lower Left  (-3205218.073, -109179.345) (164d55'11.69"E, 41d26'35.27"N)
Upper Right (  285748.266, 1589076.258) (147d50'44.26"W, 65d27' 4.19"N)
Lower Right (  408006.864,  211463.469) (147d45'27.98"W, 52d47'50.30"N)
Center      (-1459734.903,  739948.457) (178d15' 4.16"W, 55d34'58.24"N)
Band 1 Block=19587x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
Band 2 Block=19587x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
Band 3 Block=19587x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a custom CRS which sets the central meridian to 180 instead of 0.

The proj4 definition of [EPSG:3395 (WGS 84 / World Mercator)](https://epsg.io/3395) is:

```
+proj=merc +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs
```

If I change the central meridian to 180 and use that in the `gdalwarp` command instead of EPSG:3395:

```
gdalwarp -t_srs "+proj=merc +lon_0=180 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs" input.tif output.tif
gdalinfo output.tif
```

I get an output like so:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: output.tif
       output.tif.aux.xml
Size is 20936, 14621
Coordinate System is:
PROJCRS["unknown",
    BASEGEOGCRS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
            ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        ID["EPSG",4326]],
    CONVERSION["Mercator (variant A)",
        METHOD["Mercator (variant A)",
            ID["EPSG",9804]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",180,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",1,
            SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
            ID["EPSG",8805]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["easting",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]],
        AXIS["northing",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
Origin = (-3054171.234459184575826,9689316.348941301926970)
Pixel Size = (317.323442552925542,-317.323442552925542)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-3054171.234, 9689316.349) (152d33'50.09"E, 65d27' 4.19"N)
Lower Left  (-3054171.234, 5049730.295) (152d33'50.09"E, 41d26'37.55"N)
Upper Right ( 3589312.359, 9689316.349) (147d45'23.97"W, 65d27' 4.19"N)
Lower Right ( 3589312.359, 5049730.295) (147d45'23.97"W, 41d26'37.55"N)
Center      (  267570.562, 7369523.322) (177d35'46.94"W, 55d13'11.35"N)
```

[image]

Note: `input.tif` is just some dummy data with the same dimensions and CRS as Lambert.tif derived from the gdalinfo output included in the question.

Comment: Lifesaver! Thank you.